# smooth scaled Schoenfeld residual plot - covariates with levels

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards, schoenfeld-residuals

I'm working with cox proportional hazard (cox-PH) in R. I'm using the smoothed scaled Schoenfeld residual plot to assess the PH assumption.

Suppose I have this model in R, disease as outcome and genetics as exposure:

```
#Residual plot for genetics:
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(start, end, disease)~1+factor(genetics)+strata(gender), robust =T, data=mydata)

#Residual plot: 
test.ph <- cox.zph(cox_model)
plot(test.ph, resid = FALSE)
```

The covariate genetics has levels in it. Meaning I have made a loop for the cox regression so it can run (make the analysis) for every single level in the covariate genetics. The levels are named like this geneA and geneB. So the covariate genetics has two levels.

When I run a PH test in R, and I look at the residual plot, then it says that the covariate on the plot is genetics. It does not show me if it is geneA or geneB. Then I tried to specify the model, so I can visualise the residual plot seperatly for geneA and geneB, like this:

```
#Residual plot for geneA:
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(start, end, disease)~1+factor(genetics==geneA)+strata(gender), robust =T, data=mydata)

#Residual plot
test.ph <- cox.zph(cox_model)
plot(test.ph, resid = FALSE) 



#Residual plot for geneB:
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(start, end, disease)~1+factor(genetics==geneB)+strata(gender), robust =T, data=mydata)

#Residual plot
test.ph <- cox.zph(cox_model)
plot(test.ph, resid = FALSE)
```

I get two different plots (which is not a surprise). But what I'm confused about is, that the first plot I get with genetics as the covariate, looks different from the plots of geneA and geneB.
So the conclusion is I get three different residual plots, one for geneA, second for geneB and a third for the covariate genetics with both levels?

My question is, how should I interpret the smooth scaled Schoenfeld residual plot that shows the covariate genetics? Is it a combination of both geneA and geneB? And what does that combination mean?

Many thanks in advance !!! :)

**Update: I'm using a 3 level co-factor, meaning genetics has 3 levels saying geneA, geneB and none. EdM has answered my Q below**

Comment: Please edit the question to add a sample model summary and the corresponding residual plots. I’m not sure that I understand the situation just from the written description. It might have to do with the choice of reference level for the categorical predictor.

Comment: If a categorical predictor has more than 2 levels, the `cox.zph()` function (in recent versions) can provide either an overall plot for the predictor or plots for individual levels versus the reference. When you edit the question, please specify the version of the software that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for answering @EdM. I'm working in a closed system that makes me unable to copy paste codes. I would have to manually write more than 30 lines of coding. I hope my following comment can clarify my Q.

Comment: It's the newest version of cox.zph() I'm using. It is exactly what it's providing me - an overall plot for the predictor, genetics (which has two levels, geneA and geneB). So it's showing me one plot with one curve for both geneA and geneB. My Q is, how should I interpret the overall plot? Because when I look at the individual levels plot (geneA and geneB separately), they look different from each other. So what is the overall plot showing? The average HR over time for both geneA and geneB? Or how should I think about it?

Comment: I have updated the question with adding a short example of what I have written in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to isolate individual levels of `genetics` isn't doing what you think. The question that you raise about interpretation of Schoenfeld plots is the same as you might have raised about interpretation of model coefficients.

For a 2-level factor you are evaluating the *difference* in outcome between the 2 levels. You are *always* thus including both levels in the calculations and plots. The only issue is the *direction* of the difference, set by the choice of reference level. All 3 models you show in your question are the same except for their choice of reference level of the `genetics` factor.

If you don't specify otherwise, the reference level for a factor is the lowest in alphanumeric order of the level names, presumably `geneA` in your data. The regression coefficient is for the log-hazard *difference* between the second level and the reference level, or for `geneB-geneA` in this case.

When you specify `factor(genetics==geneA)` instead, you are simply reversing the choice of reference level. Both `geneA` and `geneB` cases are still included, but the reference level is now for a value of 0 (FALSE) for `genetics==geneA`; that is, the reference level is now `geneB` and the regression coefficient is for the `geneA-geneB` log-hazard difference. Specifying `factor(genetics==geneB)` just re-reverses the reference-level choice and gives the same model as you get with `factor(genetics)`.

Here's are reproducible examples based on the `lung` dataset built into the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival), similar to your models. Sex is coded `Male=1, Female=2`, providing a 2-level categorical predictor like your `genetics`. I included 2 strata based on the `inst` numbers distinguishing treating institutions. There's no need to include the `1` in the formula, but I kept it to match your code.

```
library(survival)
mod1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1 + factor(sex) + strata(inst<10), data=lung)
mod2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1 + factor(sex==1)+ strata(inst<10), data=lung)
mod3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1 + factor(sex==2)+ strata(inst<10), data=lung)
```

The coefficients for `mod1` and `mod3` are the same; their scaled Schoenfeld residual plots are the same except for the y-axis label. The coefficient for `mod2` is just the negative of that for the other models; its scaled Schoenfeld residual plot is a mirror image of the others. Both levels of `genetics` are involved in all models and plots.

You should know that things are a bit more complicated with a factor having 3 or more levels. Then the `terms` argument to `cox.zph()` determines whether you evaluate all levels together or evaluate each other level relative to the reference level.

*In response to comments*

Comments on this answer indicate that the `genetics` predictor actually was a 3-level categorical predictor, with levels `none` (the reference), `geneA` (for one type of variant), and `geneB` (for a different variant).

In that case the first residual plot produced by the code in the question, with the default `terms=TRUE` argument to `cox.zph()`, combines the scaled Schoenfeld residuals over *all levels* of `genetics`. That's analogous to how an `anova()` function combines a test over all levels of a categorical predictor, and is probably the most useful analysis and plot for evaluating PH for `genetics`.

With the 3-level `genetics` predictor, the second and third models in the question still didn't do what might have been intended. The `factor(genetics==geneA)` model compared `geneA` cases against the *combination* of `none` and `geneB` cases, and similarly for the `factor(genetics==geneB)` model. I suspect that neither the models nor their PH assessments would be very useful in practice.

If for some reason you want separate analyses and plots for `geneA` versus `none` and for `geneB` versus `none`, specify `terms=FALSE` in `cox.zph()`.

Comment: As always, thanks a lot EdM! You are so good at explaining stuff about cox regression. I finally understand it now. I was confused before because I thought that the reference level was those who did not carry the cofactor genetics (meaning neither geneA or geneB). That's why I was confused about what the plot was showing. what if I wanted to see if the PH assumption is hold true between those carring the genetics and those who does not (the outcome would still be disease). Would that make sense to compare?

Comment: @SAphi11 perhaps you are already using a 3-level `genetics` predictor? That would make sense if the only (and mutually exclusive) options were `none`, `geneA` and `geneB`. Look at `summary(factor(my.data$genetics))`. If you aren't, I would recommend that. In that case you could set the reference level (via `relevel()`) to be those without either of `geneA` or `geneB`. You would choose, with the `terms` argument to `cox.zph()`, whether to get an overall estimate of PH combining all levels (my favorite) or to evaluate each of `geneA` and `geneB` separately with respect to the reference level.

Comment: I missed that detail. I am using a 3-level genetics as you say. It's a none, geneA and geneB. So wouldn't that change the interpretation of the first plot I got from R, by visualising the PH test by only specifying the cofactor genetics (the plot that provided me results with genetics on the y-axis). Because then I don't understand which of the levels it is using as a reference and what it is compared to. When you say "get an overall estimate of PH combining all levels". Does that mean that level 0, A and B are all combined? Or the combination of geneA or geneB and comparing it to not carrying

Comment: I just found out that, the reference level by default is none (as it is assigned a zero as factor). So I'm suspecting that the first residual plot I got, used none as ref, and combined the HR of geneA and B. Does that make sense? and was it that one you pointed out as you favorite?

Comment: @SAphi11 I've added a bit to the end of the answer to cover the 3-level situation.

Comment: thank you so much! but when you write  "the first residual plot....combines the scaled Schoenfeld residuals over all levels of genetics". What is then used as a ref? none=0 ? and then the curve/line in the plot (the HR over time), is that the average HR of gene a and gene b?

Comment: @SAphi11 thinking about your case more, I'd recommend using `terms=FALSE` in `cox.zph()`, as that would directly show how much either of the `geneA` or `geneB` coefficients (with `none` as the reference) might violate PH. With the default `terms=TRUE`, `cox.zph()` returns _coefficient-weighted_ residual sums over all non-reference levels. The curve is then for the "linear predictor" including all non-reference levels, for which the combined coefficient is 1.  The curve with `terms=TRUE` shows the shape in time of overall PH violation, but not which level(s) might be responsible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It all makes more sense now!! I have by now done both thing. And everything's works. I have made residual plots for all combined, aswell as residual plots showing geneA vs. none, and geneB vs. none.  In your opinion, what would be best to include in a paper (in the supplementary)? I'm interested in including less plots. So wouldn't it still be okay to visually inspect the residual plots by looking at all the levels combined? Without necessary looking at how  each level is contributing to the predictor line, as long as the PH assumption is hold?

Comment: I see that it might be a problem if including a plot that violates PH without showing which of the levels that contribute to that. I would really like to hear your opinion on this

Comment: @SAphi11 if PH isn't violated, why show plots at all? If it is violated for a categorical predictor, what to show depends on the nature of the predictor. If there's no clearly defined reference level, the combined plot with `terms=TRUE` is OK. You, however, have a substantively meaningful reference (`none`) and are specifically interested in how `geneA` and `geneB` are associated with outcomes different from those with `none`. With a substantively meaningful reference, you probably want to use `terms=FALSE`. Don't worry about how many figures to include in a supplement.

Comment: it is because the PH is violated when only testing by cox.zph. But the visual inspection with residual plots shows almost a linear line. So I wanted to show that the PH is not violated by visual inspection. But I see what you mean. It makes more sense to have the none as a reference for each level. But then in which case would you use the combined residual plot?

Comment: @SAphi11 the combined residual plot makes sense when the choice of reference level is arbitrary and all levels are more or less equivalent in terms of the hypothesis that you are testing. My sense is that you are more interested in the differences of each of `geneA` and `geneB` from `none`, so the separate plots seem to make more sense in your situation.

Comment: as always, a big thank you!! I definitely see what you mean.